# Change account owner of Opportunity if it meets criteria in Apex Class

Tags: apex, class, ownership

I've written an apex class to update all Opportunities which meet a certain criteria. I understand how to change the fields values on that specific opportunity, but am confused to how I would change the associated account's owner. Here's what I've written so far:

````js
public with sharing class ChangeOppOwnerToProcessing implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,Schedulable {

    private static final String STAGE_0 = '0 - Prospecting';
    private static final String CL = 'Closed Lost 0-1';
    private static final String lostReason = 'Expired Timeline';

    public static Id processingUserId = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Name = 'Processing'].Id;

    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        String query = 'SELECT Id, OwnerId, DaysSinceCreated__c, StageName, RecordTypeId, McaApp__Reason_Lost__c' +
            'FROM Opportunity WHERE Owner.Name != \'Processing\'';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Opportunity> scope) {

        update getOppsToUpdate(scope);
    }

    private List<Opportunity> getOppsToUpdate(List<Opportunity> scope) {
        System.debug('scope*****'+scope);
        List<Opportunity> oppsToUpdate = new List<Opportunity>();

        for(Opportunity o : scope)  {

            if (
                // Condition 1
                (o.DaysSinceCreated__c > 14 && StageName == STAGE_0) 
            ) {
                System.debug('Condition matched if******');
                o.OwnerId = processingUserId;
                o.StageName = null;
                o.McaApp__Reason_Lost__c = lostReason;
                oppsToUpdate.add(o);

            }

        }
        System.debug('oppsToUpdate***'+oppsToUpdate);
        return oppsToUpdate;
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {}

    public void execute(SchedulableContext sc)  {
          Database.executeBatch(this, 200);
    } 

}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code I ended up getting to work:

```js
public with sharing class ChangeAccOwnerToProcessing implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,Schedulable {

    private static final String STAGE_0 = '0 - Prospecting';
    private static final String CL = 'Closed Lost 0-1';
    private static final String lostReason = 'Expired Timeline';
    private static final String typeNew = 'New';
    private static final String typeNew10k = 'New - Under $10K';

    public static Id processingUserId = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Name = 'Processing'].Id;

    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        String query = 'SELECT Id, OwnerId, DaysSinceCreated__c, StageName, RecordTypeId, McaApp__Reason_Lost__c, Opportunity_Type__c, Account.Id, Account.OwnerId ' +
            'FROM Opportunity WHERE Owner.Name != \'Processing\'';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Opportunity> scope) {

        update getOppsToUpdate(scope);
    }

    private List<Opportunity> getOppsToUpdate(List<Opportunity> scope) {
        System.debug('scope*****'+scope);
        List<Opportunity> oppsToUpdate = new List<Opportunity>();

        for(Opportunity o : scope)  {

            if (
                // Type = New
                (o.DaysSinceCreated__c > 14 && o.StageName == STAGE_0 && o.Opportunity_Type__c == typeNew) ||
                // Type = New - Under $10K
                (o.DaysSinceCreated__c > 14 && o.StageName == STAGE_0 && o.Opportunity_Type__c == typeNew10k)
                // Test Condition (Owner = Tyler's User IDs)
                //(o.OwnerId == '0050H00000CcpSh') || (o.OwnerId == '0050H00000CcpShQAJ')
            ) {
                System.debug('Condition matched if******');
                o.McaApp__Reason_Lost__c = lostReason;
                o.McaApp__Funding_Amount__c = null;
                o.McaApp__Date_Funded__c = null;
                o.StageName = CL;
                for(Account acc : [SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM Account WHERE Id=: o.Account.Id]) {
                    acc.OwnerId = processingUserId;
                    update acc;
                }
                oppsToUpdate.add(o);               
            }

        }
        System.debug('oppsToUpdate***'+oppsToUpdate);
        update oppsToUpdate;
        return oppsToUpdate;
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {}

    public void execute(SchedulableContext sc)  {
          Database.executeBatch(this, 200);
    } 

}
```

Comment: Glad you make it working, however, in the future this code might be broke as you put account dml on for loop. You can put the account into list and update the list after end loop and it seems you make double update for the same opportunity you can remove update oppsToUpdate on getOppsToUpdate method as the list opportunity will get updated on execute method.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to update the owner field on Account based on Opportunity. If yes, you can update it this way

```
o.OwnerId = processingUserId;
                o.StageName = null
o.Account.OwnerId = //pass in the owner details
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I'm trying to do, thank you. I will test this to see if it works!

Comment: this did not work unfortunately, my batch failed but im unsure why

Answer (score 0):

You could try below code. It should able to update the related accounts.

```
public with sharing class ChangeOppOwnerToProcessing implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,Schedulable {

private static final String STAGE_0 = '0 - Prospecting';
private static final String CL = 'Closed Lost 0-1';
private static final String lostReason = 'Expired Timeline';

public static Id processingUserId = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Name = 'Processing'].Id;

public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    String query = 'SELECT Id, OwnerId, DaysSinceCreated__c, StageName, RecordTypeId, McaApp__Reason_Lost__c' +
        'FROM Opportunity WHERE Owner.Name != \'Processing\'';
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}

public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Opportunity> scope) {
    List<Opportunity> oppsToUpdate = new List<Opportunity>();
    List<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();
    for(Opportunity o : scope)  {

        if (
            // Condition 1
            (o.DaysSinceCreated__c > 14 && StageName == STAGE_0) 
        ) {
            System.debug('Condition matched if******');
            o.OwnerId = processingUserId;
            o.StageName = null;
            o.McaApp__Reason_Lost__c = lostReason;
            accountsToUpdate.add(o.Account);
            oppsToUpdate.add(o);
        }
    }
    for(Account acc : accountsToUpdate){
        acc.OwnerId = //userId;
    }

    update oppsToUpdate;
    update accountsToUpdate;
}

public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {}

public void execute(SchedulableContext sc)  {
      Database.executeBatch(this, 200);
} 
}
```

Comment: Hello I will try this today and see if it works

Comment: this didn't work unfortunately, even after adding a return under the two update calls.